# PHP form spoofing and validation

Tags: php, forms, validation, sanitization, spoofing

I've been reading about form spoofing and just couldn't understand why is it so important to prevent it when we can assure that the passed value(s) are properly validated? Perhaps I'm missing something here, but here's an example:

example.org/form.html:

```
<form method="post" action="post.php">
    <input type="text" name="content" value="something">
    <input type="submit" name="post" value="Post">
</form>
```

example.org/post.php:

```
if (isset($_POST['content']))
{
    $content = filter_var($_POST['content'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    //use $content as a sanitized variable, pass it to a database, etc.
}
```

A malicious user could simply change the input field in form.html to, for example, `<textarea name="content">something here</textarea>`, but how does that affect anything? We ensure that the tags are stripped from the string in the post.php script anyway.

So here's my question: is it safe to assume that, with proper input validation, PHP form spoofing should be of little to no danger in terms of security? What else could the malicious user pass to the script with the `name="content"` attribute (besides textarea, select and all other tags) that could effectively cripple the database or something? Because if there's nothing else they can do, why use tokens?

Comment: I am aware of CSRF attacks, however, I still find it difficult to grasp just _how_ could it be of concern? Why isn't proper validation and sanitization enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forms in specific grant several attack vectors.

1) sql injection attack

Unvalidated data can contain sql code, which can modify data, drop data or read data (depending on the application) within your whole databse.

2) cross site request forgery (XSRF)

If you do not make sure, that the data, you receive actually comes from your site (ie with a session persisted token), other sites can copy your webpage and act as a proxy for all requests.

The reason for doing this is, that they can then make copies of the transmitted data.
This can be used for fishing for example.

3) cross site script injection

Even if the data itself does no harm to your database and comes from your website, the input can contain javascript, which will be executed every time the content is displayed in your site. (typically can be tested with alert(1) or similar).

This can be prevented by stripping javascript away.

Comment: So I guess the only problem would be a CSRF attack, since I'm escaping the data properly and ensure that there can be no SQL injections by using PDO for all my queries.

Comment: For this small example, yes. There are more attack vectors, which are even more complicated to prevent. an example for this would be man-in-the-middle, where the attacker would change your form while it is on the way to the user. This can be prevented by https and would be a requirement for pci dss. But i did not mention that in my post, since it is a bit over the top for a small application.

Comment: I'm developing my own CMS for a blog, but I don't really think I could use https, so I presume that such security measures are a little bit out-of-scope in my project.

Comment: Yes, that's what i meant. You should be fine without https.

Answer (score 2):

The danger is if you are using any of the `$_POST` content in something like a SQL query (SQL Injection), or putting the input directly into an `exec(...)` call (not good practice anyways), etc.  As long as you are cleaning the input (validation / scrubbing) there is no danger.  The key rule is:

> Never trust input from a user.

Comment: I am using PDO to connect to the database (prepare(), execute(), placeholders) in order to prevent SQL injection. Is there still anything I should be mindful about?

Comment: SQL Injection and unintended code execution are the two big threats I try to guard against.

Comment: So basically, ensuring that _anything_ passed to the script is properly escaped should be enough to prevent the dangers of form spoofing? Because various websites really take it seriously when it comes to tokens and making sure that the form is submitted by the right user.

Comment: Tokens can be used to prevent forgery as you describe, but what are protecting at that point is really session hijacking... where a form is submitted along with some additional information (session id) to make it SEEM like it was submitted by a legit user.  That can only be prevented using a token / secure session architecture.  This isn't a real concern for 99.99% of forms on the web.